# Cannot get itemDoubleClick event to work in Flex (even with doubleClickEnabled=true)

Tags: apache-flex, double-click

I am trying to do a simple datagrid in Flex with a doubleclick event, but I cannot get `itemDoubleClick` to fire:

```
<mx:DataGrid id="gridReportConversions" height="100%" width="100%" mouseEnabled="true" doubleClickEnabled="true" itemDoubleClick="refererRowDoubleClicked(event)">
                    <mx:columns>
                        <mx:DataGridColumn width="75" dataField="qty" headerText="Qty" />
                        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="referer" headerText="URL" />
                    </mx:columns>
                </mx:DataGrid>
```

If I use the `itemClicked` event then the event is raised just fine. When I search for this problem I find many people saying 'you need to set `doubleClickEnabled=true`, but I've done that and it still doesn't work.

This control is nested within quite a few levels of VBox and other containers. Surely I dont need to set `doubleClickEnabled` on each of those containers do I?

Just to clarify how I tested this - I have an alert box in my `refererRowDoubleClicked` event handler and it never gets shown when I use `itemDoubleClick`

Comment: Please post your event handler function...I bet it is firing, but there is an error in the handler function that makes it look like it is not firing.

Comment: @mmattax - my function contains Alert.show("reached event function") and the parameter is event:Event. if I change itemDoubleClick to itemClick then I see the message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simon,

I was able to get your code to work, no problem.  Wrapped it up in several layers of containers that didn't have doubleClickEnabled set to true, to see if that was an issue, but it doesn't seem to be.

I'm wondering if one of the parents is causing a problem somehow.  Would it be possible for you to post a larger section of the code?

Here is what I ran to test this with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

            [Bindable] private var dp:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([{qty:1,referer:'http://google.com'},{qty:25,referer:'http://cnn.com'},{qty:4,referer:'http:stackoverflow.com'}]);



            private function refererRowDoubleClicked(e:Event):void
            {

                var msg:String = "target: " + e.target + "\n\ncurrentTarget: " + e.currentTarget + "\n\nselected item qty: " + gridReportConversions.selectedItem.qty + "\nselected item referer: " + gridReportConversions.selectedItem.referer;
                Alert.show(msg);
            }

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>


    <mx:VBox width="100%" height="100%">        
        <mx:VBox width="100%" height="100%">      
            <mx:Box width="100%" height="100%">
                  <mx:Canvas width="100%" height="100%">                    
                      <mx:DataGrid id="gridReportConversions" height="100%" width="100%" dataProvider="{this.dp}"
                        mouseEnabled="true" doubleClickEnabled="true" itemDoubleClick="refererRowDoubleClicked(event)">
                            <mx:columns>
                                    <mx:DataGridColumn width="75" dataField="qty" headerText="Qty" />
                                    <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="referer" headerText="URL" />
                            </mx:columns>
                      </mx:DataGrid>
                </mx:Canvas>
            </mx:Box>       
        </mx:VBox>
    </mx:VBox>

</mx:Application>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for tryin this out. i guess i'll have to take it step by step up the 'container chain' and see if i can get it to work. just wanted to mkae sure initially i wasnt doing somethin stupid

Answer (score 1):

Before I use the propety doubleClickEnabled, my itemDoubleClick doesn't work, but when I set `doubleClickEnabled=true`, it work good, no problem.